# PHP session timeout after some minutes

Tags: php, session

good morning, I am trying to create a session that times out after some minutes, I tried out the code below but it just destroys the session when I refresh the page

```
<?php
    //start session
    session_start();

    //database connection
    include('database/connection.php');

    //site config
    $site_name = "Lilaga";

    //session expiration timer
    $expireAfter = 1;

    if(isset($_SESSION['phone'])){
        $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE phone =$_SESSION[phone]");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        $name = $row['firstname'] ." ". ucfirst($row['lastname']);
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $customerID = $row['customerID'];

        $secondsInactive = time() - $_SESSION['phone'];
        $expireAfterSeconds = $expireAfter * 60;
        if($secondsInactive >= $expireAfterSeconds){
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to expire the session after X seconds even if the user is active within your page?

Comment: There are a lot of customisation options for PHP sessions, including both how long the session cookie and the server-side session data will last.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: No i want it to expire after X minutes of inactivity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at this : [PHP.net - session.gc_maxlifetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).

It's something to configure in your *php.ini*.